# How to cache Jose4j jwks key set in a restful environment

Tags: azure, caching, ehcache, concurrenthashmap, jose4j

I started using jose4j to validate Azure AD originating jwt tokens against the OpenedId Connect jwks it publishes. All in a restful environment which means no state.

To avoid recreating all the objects from scratch every time a request comes in and consequently jose4j retrieving the jwks again and again, I want to use caching.

The dilemma I have is what to cache:

1. The serialized json jwks string and do so called out of band validation and when it fails get a new jwks.
2. HttpsJwks
3. HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver
4. JwtConsumer

I was thinking JwtConsumer is the best. Any ideas on this if this is a good choice?

As the cache is shared over all restfull requests which are handled in a mulithreaded way (using cxf blueprint in Karaf) the JwtConsumer should be thread safe. Anybody know whether it is.

I was thinking to cache using ehcache or ConcurrentHashmap using the tid as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JwtConsumer` is thread safe (as long as any custom Validators or Customizers used are also thread safe). However, cacheing and reusing the [HttpsJwks](http://static.javadoc.io/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.6/org/jose4j/jwk/HttpsJwks.html) object(s) is where you'll realize the vast majority of benefit because it internally caches the keys retrieved from the jwks endpoint. Holding on to `HttpsJwks` is what will prevent jose4j from retrieving the content of jwks endpoint again and again.

Comment: Cool, so you suggest  HttpsJwks and recreate the other objects on each subsequent rest request where I validate the token:

HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver httpsJwksKeyResolver = new
 HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(https_jwks);
     
     JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
             .setVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJwksKeyResolver)
             .setExpectedAudience(clientIdAuthserver)
             .setExpectedIssuer(issuerAuthServer)
             .build();
   
  jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(authServerToken);

Thanks!

Comment: I was also looking at serializing HttpsJwks into a JSON String but i didn't see that possibility. Size wise compared to caching HttpsJwks it is mayb e better to serialize the string. Do you know how to do that? I didn't see an obvious method on HttpsJwks except for the one which returns a list of JsonWebKeys.

Comment: You could get the list of JsonWebKeys and use a JsonWebKeySet serialize  them to a JSON string. But I don't think there'd be much, if any, benefit. And it'd add a lot of work/complexity.

Comment: My final solution is/was to get the OpenID Connect document myself and extract the jwks_uri out of it, get in turn the JWKS. Both pieces of data I cache in Hazelcast, and use Jose4J to do what you call out of band validation of a received JWT from AzureAD. I invalidate the cache for a specific tid when InvalidJwtSignatureException is thrown as it might be due to a JWKS key roll over. get the discovery doc and JWKS again to re-validate the JWT and when it fails then again I know for sure the JWT is invalid and when it passes the cache is nicely updated.